# Dynamically attach Typeahead to dynamically generated inputs

Tags: jquery, typeahead

I am dynamically creating input on witch I need to attach a twitter typeahead.

Since the html is dynamically generated server side and the input tag can only be selected from it's class, the only way I have found to attach it is by using the `delegate()` Jquery function.

In order to attach the typeahead only once to every input I am using the `undelegate()` function right after the `delegate()`.

```
$(document).delegate(".receivers-input", "click", function () {
        console.log($(this)); // input.receivers-input.col-md-4.col-sm-4.col-xs-4
        $(this).undelegate($(this));
        $(this).typeahead({
            minLength: 0,
        }, {
            source: function (query, cb) {
                var Request = $.ajax({
                ...
```

This works well but I have this error message when I click on the attached typeahead :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'origType' of undefined

This is probably because of `$(this).undelegate($(this));`

Does anyone knows how to prevent this error or have another way than `delegate / undelegate` to achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I searched too far for function and haven't seen the simplest solution.
I have achieve my goal by modifying the selector...

This is the code :

```
$(this).on("click", ".receivers-input:not(.tt-input)", function () {
        $(this).typeahead({
            minLength: 0,
        }, {
```

`on` binding works like delegate, it bind the handler to every existing or future element that match the selector.

Since typeahead add some data to the input it is attached to (`tt-hint`, `tt-input`, etc...), I just add in the selector `:not` witch exclude element with the typeahead classes.

Hope this might help someone, one day.

Comment: hey i am facing the same problem can u help me ....can u help me that? this is the link to my question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181817/to-delegate-typeahead-on-dynamically-generated-input